# Scale textswab letters in exponent

Tags: math-mode, yfonts

I would like to use `\textswab` from `yfonts` in the exponent of a math expression, but it is not rendered correctly.

For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\begin{document}
$2^{\textswab{b} + b}$
\end{document}
```

is rendered as

[image]

What is the correct way to fix this?

Comment: What is the expected output, I guess you want the first b to be smaller?

Comment: Why not `\mathfrak{b}` (requires `amsfonts` or `amssymb`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `yfonts` package doesn't even define the fonts at sizes less than 10pt.

You can fix it, exploiting the fact that the fonts are now available as Type1, by defining the font yourself.

On the other hand, `amsfonts` provides `\mathfrak`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \text and much more
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for \mathfrak

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{yswab}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{yswab}{m}{n}{<->yswab}{}

\newcommand{\mathswab}[1]{\text{\usefont{U}{yswab}{m}{n}#1}}

\begin{document}

$2^{\mathswab{b} + b}\qquad 2^{\mathfrak{b}+b}$

\end{document}
```

[image]